# CRM online 2011 - access data without SDK

Tags: c#, web-services, dynamics-crm-2011

Im having big problems with extracting data from the CRM 2011. I need to do it though an SSIS task in SqlServer 2008. The problem is that the CRM SDK is .NET 4.0 and the SqlServer is .NET 2.0 - thus my custom ssis fails to install.

I want to access the webservice (or at least try to) without the use of the CRM SDK - is this possible? I dont care if I have to write my soap xml manually, i just want to connect without the SDK.

I have this code so far (consumed the WSDL from the discoveryservice):

```
BIACRMNoSdk.discoveryService.DiscoveryServiceClient client = new BIACRMNoSdk.discoveryService.DiscoveryServiceClient();            
            BIACRMNoSdk.discoveryService.DiscoveryRequest request = new BIACRMNoSdk.discoveryService.RetrieveOrganizationRequest();
            BIACRMNoSdk.discoveryService.DiscoveryResponse response = (BIACRMNoSdk.discoveryService.DiscoveryResponse)client.Execute(request);
```

Im getting a security exception, that it could not resolve my security - how to apply this security? There are no obvious places to add this. Anyone got ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Can't you just read the undelying SQL Server db ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always create a .NET 4 Web Service which uses the SDK to access the CRM2011 and exposes whatever you need... you can host that anyway you want (IIS, Windows Service etc.) and then you can consume your webservice from your custom SSIS...

Comment: Thats kinda the approach i ended up using, i wrapped my sdk in a ServicedComponent and accessed it from my .net 2.0 application

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using the OData services to get this data?

Comment: As far as i can read OData is only available from within the solution, this means from javascript etc. Have tried but cant get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Closing - cannot be done!
Seems like microsoft is deeply dependent on the SDK. If this should be done without SDK, then you probably need to be sniffing the format.